# Smart Token Security Test

Tags: penetration-test, public-key-infrastructure, smartcard

I have a question. One of my colleague gave me a `Smart Token` which consists of public/private key inside and asked me if I can test its security. I said it should be tested in a equipped lab for passing FIPS standard tests. However I was wondering if I can test this token with some tools and check if it's secure. I searched the web but I couldn't find anything useful. Does anybody here have any experience in this area? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Since my question may not be clear as I think, I put it in some practical approach, if I gave you some PKI token and show you some certificates which it has like FIPS-140, PKCS11, ... whould you use this PKI token in your secure applications? In other words, you trust a secure device by certificates which producer claims to have?? What if there is a hardware Torjan or backdoor implemented into device?

Comment: What kind of “smart token”? What security properties do you expect?

Comment: Specifically PKI smart Token, and by Security test I mean any security report about this device such as firmware test, performance test and I wish I could perform some hardware tests but I know it needs equipped laboratory. However I have to trust any certificate which the device producer claims to have.@Gilles

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach will depend on what requirements your colleague has for the system's security. The token itself performs a very simple job as part of the authentication architecture. What you'll really be testing is the behavior of the software on the server which, presumably, is provided to you by a vendor. To that end, here are a few tests that must pass, at minimum, for you to know that the system is functioning:

1. **Authentication.** Provide the correct credentials for the user
   associated with the token, along with the possession factor (the
   token's code), and ensure that you are able to access the system.
2. **User-factor pairing.** Provide the correct credentials for a different
   user, along with the possession factor, and ensure that
   authentication fails.
3. **Factor invalidation.** Provide the same possession factor twice in
   succession, along with valid credentials, and ensure that
   authentication fails the second time.
4. **Factor expiration.** Provide a sufficiently old possession factor
   along with valid credentials and ensure that authentication fails.

**Edit:** My answer assumes that you are dealing with a disconnected, multi-factor authentication token. Most commonly, these are time-synchronized. Forgive me for not prodding further if you are dealing with a connected token like a [smart card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card).